# How do I use a different username and email address when trying to sign up on a site, using Selenium IDE?

Tags: email, selenium, ide

So what I'm trying to automate is signing up on the website I'm working on and I need a different username and email address each time.
As email client I would use mailinator, and I need a different name for the user (for example user1, user2, user3, etc) and corresponding email addresses (user1@mailinator.com, user2@mailinator.com, etc).

I would prefer to only use Selenium IDE as much as possible since I'm new in the field and don't know much programming.

Thanks.

Comment: You are stretching the boundaries of what the IDE is designed to do. Don't be shy of learning something new (a programming language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here add this to your IDE, it will generate new email with help of today date

Email format: **testuser11-08-2013-10-10-10@test.com**

Random number format: **today date + random number**

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth()+1; var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); var hour = today.getHours(); var min = today.getMinutes(); if(dd&lt;10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm&lt;10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy+ '-'+hour+'-'+min+'-' + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);}</td>
    <td>number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>testuser${number}@test.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Andrian. Your answer was just what I was looking for; dare to say even more than that. Keep up the good work.